# Jquery Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

i'm using an datatable reordering script and it seems somehow it's not compatible with jquery 1.11.1. How can i retype it to get rid of this error? Here is the line where i get the error

```
 function fnGetState(oTable, sSelector, id) {

            var tr = $("#" + id, oTable);
```

error is:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #

....value:null},fb.error=function(a){throw new Error("Syntax error, unrecognized ex...
```

Comment: Your id seems to be an empty string. But your whole selection is strange. Why are you looking in the oTable element ? `$('#someId')` is faster than `$('#someId',someElement)`

Comment: If you provide more code, it would be easier to help you. Have you checked the values of the variables you're using? `id` and `oTable`

Comment: @DenysSéguret Even with an empty id, `$()` shouldn't throw a syntax error. The problem is likely not in the posted code @ OP what's `fb.error`?

Comment: pff true, it seems i had to add an id to the `<tr>`. Thnx for opening my eyes